# Disabling ASP.NET Session refresh for specific request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax, session

We have a website that has a 20 minute session timeout and our users want a 10 minute session expiry warning. At the moment we're using a control which kinda does the job but it isn't AJAX aware and so pops up even if the user has been doing stuff.

I have an idea to get around this by just polling the server every 2 minutes to find out how long the user has left on their session. But after research i can not find out if its possible to say "This request shouldn't refresh the timeout", which is crucial as the act of polling would inadvertently refresh the session timeout.

Is this possible, or am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only reliable way you can do this is to modify your ajax javascript to extend the timeout on your existing script.

You could use the disable session state for a page then modify your app to store the last access time for a user in the db. poll the session-less page to find out when the user last did something.

Either way you'll have to make extensive changes across your app.

Comment: We made a modification to Ajax Pro to call the reset method on every response from the server. Seems to work well. Thanks for your input - apologies for the delayed action.

Answer (score 0):

If your session has a fixed 20 minute expiry, then it won't get extended by refreshing a page. However, if you want to have a script on your page to alert users of their imminent session expiry, then you'll need to set a client side script (presume Javascript) and kick it off on page load?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertSessionTimeout(){ alert("Your session is about to expire. Please refresh the page.") }
window.setTimeout('alertSessionTimeout', 10*60*1000);
</script>
```

Comment: I think that's what the OP said he was already doing. Refreshing the page will extend the session if it hits the server. Every request to the server extends the session.

Answer (score 0):

what about TWO web applications accessing the same database? in the first, the main, application you write last access time to database, and the second application is polled via ajax to get inactive time base on last access time...

Comment: I like your thinking :) - I'll discuss with my colleagues to see if this is feasable for us.

Answer (score 0):

In polling the server you see how long is left you would be resetting it back to 20 minutes. You would need to make sure the request does not attach the session cookie to prevent this. In doing so you create another problem in that you can't access the user session.

An alternative is just do in JavaScript page load using SetTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some people are confusing Session state with Forms Authentication ticket expiration. Session state has an automatic sliding expiration - if session is set for 20 minutes and after 19 minutes of talking to your friend in the office, you request a page, you get another 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I have a similar problem and had this idea for a solution.

Upon each page request that uses the session, your session gets refreshed. Into the application cache, put key=sessionId and value=DateTime.Now.

Create a web service (.ashx or what have you) that does NOT use session state, but ideally is authenticated using Forms Authentication or some other authentication scheme. Your javascript, which is counting down the time until session expiration, will call this web service shortly before the session expires to see if the session is really going to expire.

I'm thinking the web service should return something simple like a 2 if the session is expired, 1 if the session is about to expire, or 0 if not. Return random [0,1,2] if the service is called by a user with an unknown or invalid SessionId cookie -- this would hopefully prevent valid sessionId discovery by an attacker who gets a Forms Auth cookie.

I investigated decompiling the built-in SessionProvider to see if I could access the session to discover the expiration without triggering a refresh. But doing so is dependent on the type of session provider being used, so if you ever move from, say, SQL Server session provider to Redis, you have to rewrite it.